# Рендер виджетов Qt с помощью GPU, вместо CPU

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, opengl, qt6

Всем привет, имеется проблема.

Я обнаружил, что большое количество теней и блюр создают подвисания, т.к рендерится как оказалось на CPU, и я подумал, а можно ли как-то перевести рендер на GPU?

Как вообще это сделать? Как мне говорят, возможно используй **qopenglwidget**, но я не понимаю, мне придется прям писать в стиле OpenGL?

Прошу дельного совета и примера кода, когда обычные виджеты рендерятся через GPU.

Comment: Обычные виджеты не рендерятся через GPU.

Comment: @user7860670 Да, я понял это. Но можно ли как-то переложить нагрузку? Или мне придется прям все с нуля виджеты делать в OpenGL?

Comment: Ну если уж вам хочется везде блюр и прочие финтифлюшки, то наверное да. Еще можно QT quick посмотреть, там же по идее браузер, ускорение на GPU наверное есть.